# How to prove that A $\subseteq$B $\implies$ |A|$\le$|B|?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

How to prove that A $\subseteq$B $\implies$ |A|$\le$|B|? 
I know that for |A|$\le$|B| there has to be a function f:A $\mapsto$B which is an injective function. But i get stuck because the sets A and B were not specified, so should i just let A and B be anything i decide ?

Comment: No, you must prove it for *all* sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A\subseteq B$. There is a very simple function from $A$ to $B$ that is an injection; in fact, it’s one of the few functions that you can write down explicitly without knowing what $A$ and $B$ are.

Comment: @JMoravitz: I certainly did, and that’s more than a nitpick; thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Consider the inclusion function:

$$f:A\to B,\quad f(a)=a\quad\forall a\in A$$

Comment: but isnt $f:A\to B,\quad f(a)=a\quad\forall a\in A$ also surjective making the sets equal to each other rather then less and equal because if it is injective and surjective then the function is bijective by definition

Comment: @Jared  If $A \subseteq B$, then the function $f: A \to B$ defined by $f(a) = a \forall a \in A$ is only surjective if $A = B$. For example, let $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $B = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$.  Observe that while $f$ is injective, it is not surjective since $4$ is not in the range.